# Message not storing in MAM archive in case of group chat

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, multiuserchat

I am using Smack muc for group chat.
I join a group and send some message.
Later when I leave and join a room back again I try to fetch message archive but I don't get any message.
Is their some way MAM archive can store muc group message ?